# How to check the status code of a function in sh?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am converting my script from bash to dash... and have problem getting the return code of a function.

```
#!/bin/sh
check_ip() {
    local netbit=`echo "$1" | awk -F\/ '{print $1}'`
    local netmask=`echo "$1" | awk -F\/ '{print $2}'`

    if case "$netbit" in
        *[!.0-9]* | *.*.*.*.* | *..* | [!0-9]* | *[!0-9] ) false ;;
        *25[6-9]* | *2[6-9][0-9]* | *[3-9][0-9][0-9]* | *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]* ) false;;
        *.*.*.* ) true ;;
        * ) false ;;
    esac; then
        if [ ! -z "$netmask" ] ; then
            if [ "$netmask" -ge 1 ] && [ "$netmask" -le 32 ] ; then
                return 0
            else
                return 1
            fi
        else
            return 0
        fi
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# this is working without the [] thing.
if check_ip "$1" ; then
    echo ok
else
    echo no
fi
```

looked up the similar script from another machine, and it has no [] as @barmar suggested.  all working now.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` command chooses the `then` or `else` clauses based on the exit status of the command. You only use `[` if you want to perform the tests defined in the `test` command; if you just want to test a specific command, you use it directly.

```
if check_ip "$ip"
then echo Good IP
else echo Bad IP
fi
```

It's also very unlikely that `$!` would be an appropriate parameter to your function. `$!` is the PID of the last background process that was started, not an IP.

Comment: thanks - but unfortunately, i tried it before and it did not work.  /bin/sh is actually a link to /bin/dash.  cheers.

Comment: You must have done it wrong, because this is definitely how it works. Put what you tried in the question.

Comment: It should work with either, this is how `if` has worked for decades. `[` is just a link to `test`, so `if [ <expression> ]` works by running the `test` command and checking its exit status. But there's nothing special about `[`, you can use any program there.

Comment: Your edited question still has the incorrect `[` in your `if` lines. Show the version that uses the syntax in my answer, but doesn't work with `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Added the semi-colon, hence: if check_ip "$1" ; then worked!!  thanks @barmar!!

Comment: Of course you need a semicolon or newline, how else is it supposed to know where the command ends?

Answer (score 2):

`$?` reads the exit status of the last command executed.

```
a() {
  return 0;
}

b() {
  return 1;
}

a;
echo $?;
b;
echo $?;
```

would return:

```
0
1
```

Comment: Should work.  Returns 0 for `127.0.0.1` and 1 for `127.0.0.999`!